# StrutsTestCase implementation - Compilation error

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, junit4, struts2-junit-plugin

I am using Struts 2 to create a web application. I am using `StrutsTestCase` for Junit test case to test the Action class. I have imported `struts2-junit-plugin-2.3.4.jar` as I am using `struts2-core-2.3.4.jar`. Inside the testcase method, when i tried to set the request parameters, request variable is not available for use. it is showing compilation error. I am getting 'request cannot be resolve' error. In my test class i am extending `StrutsTestCase` which has request as protected parameter. But it is not available inside extended method.

My test action looks like this:

```
import org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase;

public class WallPlanningActionTest extends StrutsTestCase {
    public void testList() {
    request.setParameter("salesOrg",1); 
}
```

Comment: I dont get any exception instead i get compilation error

Comment: hmm.. what's your POM ?

Comment: I don't have any POM file.

Comment: How did you resolve the same/

Answer (score 1):

You can only get compilation errors if `StrutsTestCase` which your class is extended is not `org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase`. You could optimize the imports or just use FQCN.

```
public class WallPlanningActionTest extends org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase {
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:
I had the same problem - the protected request field was not accessible. The problem was that i hadn't add the spring libraries. StrutsTestCase uses spring-core-x.y.z and spring-test-x.y.z. It is depended on them an i couldn't find a way to use the unit tests without them.
Other dependencies could be found by opening the struts-junit-plugin jar (as archive). Open the META-INF folder and in there you will find DEPENDENCIES file with a list of all dependencies.
Hope this helps someone.